# Loop through chunked array with with api request

Tags: php, arrays, api, overloading, file-get-contents

I have a function which gets data with an API request. I sending an array (called) `$result` with that request. This array contains metadata of the actual data I am posting.

**The problem is:**

The array is too big to handle for the api request.

> string(186) " invalid input too much data to parse out into domains "

So I thought of splitting up the array with this function:

```
echo ("<pre>");
print_r (smallify($result, 15));
echo ("<pre/>");

function smallify($arr, $numberOfSlices){
    $sliceLength = sizeof($arr) / $numberOfSlices;
    for($i=1; $i<=$numberOfSlices; $i++){
        $arr1 = array_chunk($arr, $sliceLength*$i);
        return $arr1;
        unset($arr1);
    }
}
```

And it works pretty well.

Now, how do I access the internal array indexes and assign them a variable so that I can loop through the api request for each chunk?

Here's the API request:

```
// The last parameter of the Domain is the the array.
// I want to make a request for every chunked array.

$domains = file_get_contents("http://www.somedomain.com/api.php?username:Pw:getinfo=$result");
var_dump($domains);
```

Comment: So are you trying to keep the original index of each item in the initial array? If that is the case, [array_cunk](http://us1.php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php) has a third, optional argument, `preserve_keys`, which will keep the original index as a key.

Comment: Well that doesnt really matter as long as I can loop the request for the chunked arrays.

Comment: So are you trying to just iterate over all the sub-arrays? Have you tried something like:

`foreach ($chunks as $chunk) {
        foreach ($chunk as $item) {
            // do something with each individual $item
        }
    } `

Comment: that could work but for some reason I get unexpected end of file ...

Comment: Sorry, might be because `// do something....` will comment out the rest of the line. Try this, or separate commands into new lines:
`foreach ($chunks as $chunk) { foreach ($chunk as $item) { /*do something with each individual $item*/ } }`

Comment: yea, got it now but the api request doesnt execute now.. I used $item as variable in the url

Comment: As soon as you call `return` in your function -- the function is done; no `unset`, no "next iterations", done.  Your error has gone away because you are only dealing with a fifteenth of the data; not because you are breaking it into 15 chunks successfully.